# Trying to compile last FFmpeg iPhone: error: invalid operand in inline asm

Tags: iphone, compilation, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile last FFmpeg for iPhone, but I am getting an error:

```
    CC  libavformat/asfcrypt.o
error: invalid operand in inline asm: 'ldr   ${0:Q}, $1  
    ldr   ${0:R}, $2  
    '
make: *** [libavformat/asfcrypt.o] Error 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried --disable-asm configuration. It works but the decoder performance is bad.

I tried edit the config.h:

`#define HAVE_INLINE_ASM 0`

this only disables inline assembly

or if you only some decoder in ffmpeg, just disable all other unused codec
and edit **libavutil/arm/intmath.h**, comment out this define:

```
#define av_clipl_int32 av_clipl_int32_arm
```

this only disable one inline assembly function and it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me on ffmpeg 0.10, OS X Lion, and Xcode 4.2. It just created other ASM errors. --disable-asm is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 7):

I'm getting the same problem. I found a way around it by disabling inline assembly language:

```
./configure --disable-asm ...
```

I'm not sure what sort of impact this will have on performance, but at least for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can used --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 this will work for you. these cpu is very old cpu we can disable it.

Comment: when you use these --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 the decoder also have high performance.